# sas how to read in this raw data file

Tags: import, sas

I have a raw data file like this:

```
JamesBrownSenior
AshleyPinkJunior
```

The first column is name. And second is a color tag. .. But for each column, the observation length varies.

I have tried this

```
data ct_11;
 infile '';
 length Name $ 10 Tag $ 10 Title $ 10;
 input Name $ Tag $ Title $;
run;
```

It didn't work. I guess I missed some options.

Comment: If you can be certain that the value for each column starts with a capital and there are no further capitals in it, i would jump to regular expressions. i.e., read in the data as one variable and apply a regex to split it in the 3 parts you need. Btw, i assume you obfuscated your infile statement for some reason, because it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no delimiter you have to read it as a single variable and then split it afterwards based on a rule. In your case tou can add a delimiter using a regular expression and then use the scan function to write the words to different variables.

```
data ct_11 (keep=name tag title);
 infile 'z:\nametagtitle.txt';
 length line $120 name tag title $40;
 input line $;
 dlmline = prxchange('s/([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)([A-Z]{1}[a-z]*)/$1 $2 $3/',-1,line);
 name = scan(dlmLine,1);
 tag = scan(dlmline,2);
 title = scan(dlmline,3);
run;
```